# Mapping through an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

i have an array of objects like this:

```
[{side: Buy, price: 100}, {side: Buy, price: 110}, {side: Sell, price: 200}, {side: Buy, price: 150} ]
```

Now i want to calculate for this array the total sum of the Buy and Sell side and for each side the average sum of the prices. To be more specific i want my output to be something like this:
Buy = 3  AvgPrice for Buy = 120
Sell = 1 AvgPrice for Sell = 200
I'm new to javascript and react so i have some difficulties. Thanks !:)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Sounds like you want to use `reduce` :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with React FYI.

Comment: I use foreach and reduce but im getting some difficulties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using `Array#forEach` and `Object.keys()`.

```js
var arr = [{side: 'Buy', price: 100}, {side: 'Buy', price: 110}, {side: 'Sell', price: 200}, {side: 'Buy', price: 150}], obj = {}, res = [];

arr.forEach(function(v){
 (obj[v.side] || (obj[v.side] = [])).push(v.price);
});
var res = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(s,a) {
  s[a] = obj[a].length;
  s['avg' + a] = obj[a].reduce((a,b) => a + b) / obj[a].length;
  return s;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can we add the output values in a single object? Great answer btw

Comment: Like obj = {aSide: 4, bSide: 8, aPrice: 123, bPrice: 12}

Comment: @user7334203 I will try

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. is it too complex?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot

Comment: Another question i have  var arr = [{side: 'Buy', price: 100, quantity: 100}, {side: 'Buy', price: 110, quantity: 100}, {side: 'Sell', price: 200, quantity: 100}, {side: 'Buy', price: 150, quantity: 100}]. I must inspite of average price the sum of quantities for each side. Any ideas?

Comment: @user7334203 Make new question and give me the link! (:

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to just iterate the array and keep a rolling average for each `side`.

```
var data = [{side: 'Buy', price: 100}, {side: 'Buy', price: 110}, {side: 'Sell', price: 200}, {side: 'Buy', price: 150} ];

var tally = { Buy: { count: 0, total: 0 }, Sell: { count: 0, total: 0 } };

data.forEach(item => {
    tally[item.side].count = tally[item.side].count + 1;
    tally[item.side].total = tally[item.side].total + item.price;
})

console.log("AvgPrice for Buy = " + (tally.Buy.total / tall.Buy.count) + " Sell = 1 AvgPrice for Sell = " + (tally.Sell.total / tall.Sell.count));
```

Comment: I think this is the most understandable solution

Comment: Just to clarify, you are hard coding the whole `tally` variable. What if there would be much more than just `Buy` and `Sell` elements? You would just write them down by hand? Unfortunately it won't work effectively, but I agree, now it's much more readable because of less code.

Comment: @Kinduser There is no point making super dynamic code when the requirements don't call for it.  When it comes to buying and selling, there aren't likely to be too many more sides that need to be added, so hard coding them makes sense for future maintainability.  Your example will work too, but will take someone a while to understand if they come back to it in a years time (or if a new developer starts on the project).

Comment: @MichaelPeyper It's not that complicated as it seems to be. I'm also just a beginner, which 5 months of experience. Anyways - I just think that when someone is deciding to make a question on so, he is expecting a high quality solution and even if he doesn't understand it - it's a motivation to keep learning.

Comment: @Kinduser each to his own.  I'll take readability over catering for non-existent requirements any day of the week.  Also,  it wouldn't take much to dynamically generate the `tally` object if such a requirement ever came about.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper It's fine, I respect that. But if you would ask me in any day of the week, I would choose to make a step further.

Answer (score 1):

Use any iterator like `forEach, for etc` to iterate the data, and use two `object` variables, one will store the `buy` data and other will store `sell` data.

Write it like this:

```js
var data = [{side: 'Buy', price: 100}, {side: 'Buy', price: 110}, {side: 'Sell', price: 200}, {side: 'Buy', price: 150} ];

var buy = {}, sell = {};

data.forEach(el => {
    if(el.side == 'Buy'){
          buy['count'] = (buy['count'] || 0) + 1;
          buy['total'] = (buy['total'] || 0) + el.price; 
    }else{
         sell['count'] = (sell['count'] || 0) + 1;
         sell['total'] = (sell['total'] || 0) + el.price; 
    }
})

console.log(buy.total/buy.count, sell.total/sell.count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

```
    var arrayBuySell=[{side: Buy, price: 100}, {side: Buy, price: 110}, {side: Sell, price: 200}, {side: Buy, price: 150} ]
var averageBuy = 0;
var averageSell = 0;
var totalbuy=0;
var totalbuycount=0;
var totalsellcount=0;
var totalsell=0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayBuySell.length; i++) {
    if(arrayBuySell[i]="Buy")
      {
       totalbuy+=arrayBuySell[i].price;
       totalbuycount=arrayBuySell[i].price.Count();
      }
     else
      {
       totalsell+=arrayBuySell[i].price;
       totalsellcount=arrayBuySell[i].price.Count();
      }
  }
averageBuy =totalbuy/totalbuycount;
averageSell=totalsell/totalsellcount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
let arr = [{side: "Buy", price: 100}, {side: "Buy", price: 110}, {side:     "Sell", price: 200}, {side: "Buy", price: 150} ];
let buyPrices = [];
let sellPrices = [];
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item.side === 'Buy') {
    buyPrices.push(item.price);
  } else if (item.side === 'Sell') {
    sellPrices.push(item.price);
  }
});

let avgBuy = buyPrices.reduce((a, b) => a + b)/buyPrices.length;
console.log(`Buy -> ${buyPrices.length}
AvgBuyPrices -> ${avgBuy}`);
let avgSell = sellPrices.reduce((a, b) => a + b)/sellPrices.length;
console.log(`Sell -> ${sellPrices.length}
AvgSellPrices -> ${avgSell}`);
```